# How can I make my countdown timer loop in C# using virtual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am reading a book on `C#` in my spare time (Very new to `programming`, pardon my inexperience) and have made it as far as making a `timer` for afking on a game I play. I simply cant figure out how to make the countdown timer reset itself without having to re run the program manually. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much.

```
public class Afktimer
{
    public void StartProgram()
    {
        SnapsEngine.SetTitleString("Afk Timer");
        SnapsEngine.Delay(3.0);
        SnapsEngine.SpeakString("Twenty minutes remaining");
        SnapsEngine.Delay(600.0);
        SnapsEngine.SpeakString("Ten minutes remaining");
        SnapsEngine.Delay(300.0);
        SnapsEngine.SpeakString("Five minutes remaining");
        SnapsEngine.Delay(240.0);
        SnapsEngine.SpeakString("One minute remaining");
        SnapsEngine.Delay(60.0);
        SnapsEngine.SpeakString("Timer resetting");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simply run `StartProgram` again when you want to reset the timer!

Comment: Just a quick note, more for your specific project than programming. Assuming this is an RS afk timer, you may want to have a button that you click to reset the timer. At least then you'll have a more exact time of when you reset the 20 min combat log.

Comment: Excellent guess. you are correct. I unfortunately wouldnt even know where to begin. The above code is the first I've really managed to write that serves any purpose, how ever insignificant. Would I find out how to add a button in some form of documentation?

Comment: The 20 minute timer gave it away :-) Take a look into `WPF` (Windows Presentation Foundation) which is how standard Windows applications are made (broadly speaking). You should be able to create a WPF project from within Visual Studio.

Comment: put a while loop with condition 1=1 around the content of StartProgram make the program run infinitely. you can replace the 1=1 with a boolean variable, whose value change with some user event, like a button click. is that you want?

Comment: @JayGould I Created a WPF, Added a background image to the app, but am Currently lost on where and how to add the above code to the form? Please let me know if they way I'm asking questions here is incorrect.

Comment: You should have a MainWindow.xaml (unless you renamed it) and a MainWindow.cs file. Put the code above in its own method in the `.cs` and then fire the method on a button press!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the delay as input parameter to a function. For example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var delays = new List<int> { 600, 300, 240, 60 }; // List with delays.
            delays.ForEach(delay => StartProgram(delay)); // For each element in delays call StartProgram.
        }

        public static void StartProgram(int delay)
        {
            SnapsEngine.SpeakString("{0} minutes remaining", delay / 60);
            SnapsEngine.Delay(delay);
        }
    }
}
```

The list contains your information about the different delays. Each element of the list get passed to the method `StartProgram` as input parameter. The method print the string and wait for the amount of time.

Comment: A nice solution but a little complicated for someone who stated they were new to programming perhaps?

Comment: @jay-gould Probably. I won't disagree, but `Collections` and `Linq` are key elements these days in c#.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [`StopWatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You have methods such as `Reset` and `Restart` that will suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way I can see is to just run it through a while statement so it would be something like

```
public class Afktimer
{
    public void StartProgram()
    {
        while (true)
        {
           SnapsEngine.SetTitleString("Afk Timer");
           SnapsEngine.Delay(3.0);
           SnapsEngine.SpeakString("Twenty minutes remaining");
           SnapsEngine.Delay(600.0);
           SnapsEngine.SpeakString("Ten minutes remaining");
           SnapsEngine.Delay(300.0);
           SnapsEngine.SpeakString("Five minutes remaining");
           SnapsEngine.Delay(240.0);
           SnapsEngine.SpeakString("One minute remaining");
           SnapsEngine.Delay(60.0);
           SnapsEngine.SpeakString("Timer resetting");
        }
    }
}
```

it'll just keep restart it until you close the program manually